# Well Formatted Whatsapp messages from Android App

Tags: android, whatsapp

I can send whatsapp message from android app, but it is not well formatted. by using * I can make the text bold but how to make separate paras? Can anyone help with the code. Thank you. I search the google and youtube but no one talks about formatting part.

Comment: Hii All, I used \n and it started taking it in next line. Anyways thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I used \n in between 2 lines and it took the matter in the next line. So query is solved. Thanks for help anyways.